# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined this.setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am getting the following error

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

I am trying to store Axios get results into a variable and show it in MUI Datatable before render method, and I need to access these values in another class as well.
But when i try to set variable value in this.setState, it gives error and blank page shows up.
I am also binding method in the constructor.
Here is my code

```
    export default class myList extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
        this.state = { isLoading: true, myData: undefined };
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get(url).then(data => {
            this.setState({ myData: data.data,  isLoading: false });
        });
        }
    
        render() {
        const { isLoading, myData } = this.state;
    
        if (isLoading) {
            return <div className="myList">Loading...</div>;
        }
        const columns = [
        {
            name: 'id', // field name in the row object
            label: 'ID', // column title that will be shown in table
            options: {
                display: false,
            },
        },
        {
            name: 'Name',
            label: 'name',
            options: {
                display: false,
                customBodyRender: (value) => {
                    return value === null ? "-" : value
                    },
            },
        },
        {
            label: "Actions",
            name: "action",
            options: {
                customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
                    return (
                        <Fragment>
                            <button style={{border: '0px', backgroundColor: 'white'}} onClick={() =>window.$cl_id  =tableMeta.rowData[0] }>
                             </button> </Fragment> 
                    
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        ]
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                <div className="myList">
                    <MUIDataTable
                        title={'My Data'}
                        data={myData }
                        columns={columns}
                        options={{
                            selectableRows: false, // set checkbox for each row
                            elevation: 0,
                            rowsPerPage: 10,
                            rowsPerPageOptions: [10, 20, 40, 80, 100],
                            }}
                    />
                </div>
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are `columns` and `leadList` defined?

Comment: Why have You used props if your not using it anywhere in this page and how are you passing the props here in this component?

Comment: I edited the code, 
Columns are defined in render() and data is populated through API.
In the last column I am adding a button where onClick = assign current row value. 
Actually I wanted to called a function before render(), so I can avoid "undefined" value error.

Comment: "this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);" I think this line is unnecessary! Because reacts already provides componentDidMount for us and binds it to our component.